# Access UINavigationItem from within MAUI ContentPage (in order to add native buttons to navigationbar)

Tags: c#, ios, uikit, maui

I'm writing a MAUI app, in which I'd like to add native buttons to an iOS title bar. As I understand it, I need to call `SetRightBarButtonItems` on the top-most `NavigationItem`, which for a single-page app should be MainPage. I've tried adding the following code to MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    #if IOS
    var settingsButton = new UIBarButtonItem() { 
        Title="Settings",
        Image = UIImage.GetSystemImage("gearshape")
    };
    var ni = Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController().NavigationItem;
    ni.Title = "TEST!!";
    ni.SetRightBarButtonItems([settingsButton],true);
    #endif
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be getting the correct ViewController - or it doesn't reflect the changes correctly (even the title property doesn't work). It's getting a ViewController, which isn't the case if I try running this in AppShell.xaml.cs, but anything I do to it doesn't get reflected in the UI - what is it i'm missing here?

Comment: In MAUI, the button is supported to [be set on the TitleBar of ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-8.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar). Do you want to replace this method with iOS native button?

Comment: Yes I'd like to replace it with an iOS native button, so that it feels more native, and so that I can access all the properties of UIBarButtonItem (including setting an icon via `UIImage.GetSystemImage()`)

Comment: Does your Maui program use the [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-8.0) structure or [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-8.0) ? The NavigationPage structure needs to use [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0#page-handlers) to set UIBarButtonItem, and Shell needs to use renderer.

Comment: It uses Shell - I thought custom renderers were just there for compatibility with Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Most renderers in MAUI have switched to handlers, but some views and pages still use renderers, including Shell. You can refer to the list in the link: [View handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0#view-handlers)